# регулярные выражения: исключить первый знак если он - а включить остальные

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть выражения типа:

-a + b - y * c / d ^ 2
и
a + b - y * c / d ^ 2

нужно получить все знаки + - * ^ кроме первого если он есть

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Iy43Si/1 `(?:(?!^)-|[+*\/^])` - попробуйте такое выражение

Comment: @ipatev_nn На мой взгляд, отличное решение. Причем, что интересно, в этом примере **Negative Lookbehind** `(?<!^)` работает идентично **Negative Lookahead** `(?!^)`. Не уверен, но вероятно, это потому, что `^` имеет нулевую длину

Comment: @АлексейР, тут скорее всего причина в том, что `^` это начало строки и не имеет позиции в тексте, поэтому подходят просмотры и вперед и назад. Но это как предположение)

Comment: @ipatev_nn возможно, я не очень рабираюсь в регулярках, но выглядит, что вы лишнего наворотили `(?!^)[-+*\/^]` - https://regex101.com/r/tyihhG/1

Comment: @splash58, не совсем так, я сделал под условия, которые понял в вопросе, ваше рег не будет захватывать любой символ в начале строки `-+*/^` у меня ограничение установлено только на минус. Условия в вопросе: **исключить первый знак если он** `-` **а включить остальные**

Comment: я, конечно, заголовок не читал :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[-+*^]
```

и ищите не с начала строки, а со следующего символа :)

или так - в данном случае полностью игнорируется любой из `-+*^` если он стоит первым

```
(?<!(^))[-+*^]
```

Comment: Но ведь минус все равно будет выбираться, а так же в условии тут просили именно `-` в начале игнорировать.

Comment: а я понял что надо любой знак из 4 если он стоит в самом начале игнорировать

Comment: (?<!(^))[-+*^]  - как такое прочитать?

Comment: 1) `[символы которые надо искать]` - т.е. `[-+*^]` говорит о том, что надо найти 4 символа `-`, `+`, `*`, `^` (надо только аккуратно ставить, а то `^`  в начале `[]` является отрицанием, а `-` в середине - диапазон (например `a-z` - от `a` до `z`) 2) `(?<!какого текста не должно быть перед искомым текстом)` - показывает, что будем искать символы в `[]` но перед которыми не будет текста указанного в `(?<!...)` 3) `(^)` - означает начало строки (если бы я не поставил `()`, то текст не искался бы, если бы перед ним стоял символ `^`, а когда поставил `()` - это воспринимается как начало строки

Comment: Большое спасибо